# Как на Delphi написать программу для построения 3d-графиков

Tags: delphi, 3d

Конкретно требуется написать программу для отображения графика функции заданной пользователем, при этом обязательно должны присутствовать такие функции как вращение, масштабирование (общее и по одной из осей), отображение выборки по заданному диапазону значений аргумента, также хотелось бы увидеть код для анализа полученного графика. Прошу просто натолкнуть каким образом можно реализовать данную задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего openGL, это буквально несколько строчек кода. Либо руками, тогда посмотри в тему матрицы проекции.

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с [IonRod](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/3239/ionrod)

еще можно посоветовать использовать движок для OpenGL если не работали напрямую с API, я использовал [GLScene](http://sourceforge.net/projects/glscene/)